# false | true; echo $?

Tags: bash, errorlevel

If you have a chain of commands piping input to each other, and you want the error level of the first command in the chain, how do you do that?

For example, this:

```
false | true; echo $?
```

will return '0', from 'true'. How can I get the error level of 'false' in this example?

Comment: `pipefail` in Bash

Comment: and `$PIPESTATUS`, see `man bash`

Comment: $PIPESTATUS is what I was after! Sorry for the duplicate. Thanks!